# Mod or similar formula to convert fiscal year month to calendar year month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help figuring out how to convert my companies fiscal year month (and quarter) to calendar year month (and quarter) **using mod or similar function**. I already know how to do this using the if function.

I figured out how to convert CY to FY using mod but for the life of me cannot figure out FY to CY. I tried variations of the CY to FY solutions I have but cannot get to the solution.

CYQ to FYQ
=1+MOD(C2,4)

CYMON to FYMON
=MOD((C8)+2,12)+1

I need to figure out the reverse of what in this image and come up with something similar to my formulas, if possible. I don't want a lengthy formula or to use if.

[image]

Comment: I posted an answer with IF function then deleted it as I re-read this part of your question "I already know how to do this using the if function". If that is the case, why do you want to absolutely use the inverse MOD?

Comment: I came up with `=4-MOD(-FYQ+1,4)`. Don't ask me how negative mod works. Alternative longer formulas (for the monthly conversion) would have used `SWITCH()` or `XLOOKUP()`

Comment: Your formula `=MOD((C8)+2,12)+1` seems to work fine here.  Although you don't need the parentheses around C8.  `=MOD(C8+2,12)+1` also works.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio 1) The mod solution only references the source cell once which lends itself better to copy and paste to other cells/sheets. I also know I can achieve this effect with a combo of the let and if function. 2) compared to let/if the mod solution is shorter 3) also I plan to translate this to a SQL solution for a similar use case and want to practice using mod in SQL. 4) its just more elegant to me.

Comment: @daniellopez46 Understood. Have you tested the formulae provided by gns100 and Ron Rosenfeld?

Comment: @gns100 that's the solution I was looking for! post it please and I will mark it. I also found this as two possible solutions for converting FY month to CY month: 1+MOD(cell-4,12) or 1+MOD(H25+8,12).

Comment: Ron Rosenfelds is a restatement of a solution I provided in my op.

Comment: @daniellopez46, mathematically x+8 (mod 12) and x-4 (mod 12) are always equal. That is why your two formulas for converting FY month to CY month give the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modular arithmetic works on numbers starting with 0. For example, integers to mod 4 are 0, 1, 2 or 3. So numbering the calendar year quarters as 0 for January-March, 1 for April-June, etc and similarly numbering the financial year quarters as 0 for October-December, 1 for January to March, we get

FYQ0 = MOD(1+CYQ0,4) and CYQ0 = MOD(3+FYQ0, 4)

where, FYQ0 and CYQ0 are, respectively, the financial year and calendar year quarter numbers when numbered from zero. (Hint: to determine the constant amount to add inside the MOD function, look at the required result when the value to be converted is zero).

Conventionally, quarters are numbered from 1 to 4, not 0 to 3, so FYQ = 1+FYQ0 and CYQ = 1+CYQ0 where FYQ and CYQ are, respectively, the financial year and calendar year quarter numbers when conventionally numbered.

Substituting for CYQ0 in the equation for FYQ0 yields

FYQ0 = MOD(1+(CYQ-1),4) = MOD(CYQ, 4)

So that

FYQ = 1+FYQ0 = 1+MOD(CYQ,4)   [Equation 1]

The same process for CYQ yields

CYQ0 = MOD(3+(FYQ-1), 4) = MOD(2+FYQ, 4)

and

CYQ=1+MOD(2+FYQ,4)   [Equation 2]

For month numbers, a similar process leads to

FYMON0 = MOD(3+CYMON0,12)

and

CYMON0 = MOD(9+FYMON0, 12)

so that

FYMON = 1 + MOD(2+CYMON, 12)    [Equation 3]

and

CYMON = 1 + MOD(8+FYMON, 12)    [Equation 4]

The four equations provided the basis of formulas for converting quarter/month numbers between financial years  and calendar years when conventional numbering of 1-4 is used for quarters and 1-12 for months.

Comment: An above and beyond explanation that I appreciate very much.

Comment: The "trick" to remember when converting counting numbers (1,2,3,...) using the `MOD` function is: subtract 1, convert, add 1 back.